# Salt command takes about 5 Seconds to finish

Tags: salt-stack

One of my Saltstack Installations always has a 5 Second Delay on every salt command i run on it, i.e this Command takes 5.236 Seconds to run, while a different System does not have the Delay.

It Appears that the minion (running on the Same machine as the master) does not tell the Master that it has finished it's command, the Commands are eventually running fine Though.

**"Trace" Output of the slow Environment**

```
root@salt01-master:~# time salt -l trace 'salt01-master' test.ping
[DEBUG   ] Reading configuration from /etc/salt/master
[DEBUG   ] Using cached minion ID from /etc/salt/minion_id: salt01-master
[DEBUG   ] Missing configuration file: /home/admin-user/.saltrc
[TRACE   ] None of the required configuration sections, 'logstash_udp_handler' and 'logstash_zmq_handler', were found the in the configuration. Not loading the Logstash logging handlers module.
[DEBUG   ] Configuration file path: /etc/salt/master
[DEBUG   ] Reading configuration from /etc/salt/master
[DEBUG   ] Using cached minion ID from /etc/salt/minion_id: salt01-master
[DEBUG   ] Missing configuration file: /home/admin-user/.saltrc
[DEBUG   ] MasterEvent PUB socket URI: ipc:///var/run/salt/master/master_event_pub.ipc
[DEBUG   ] MasterEvent PULL socket URI: ipc:///var/run/salt/master/master_event_pull.ipc
[DEBUG   ] Sending event - data = {'_stamp': '2016-05-24T14:13:25.267566'}
[TRACE   ] get_event() received = {'tag': 'salt/event/new_client', 'data': {'_stamp': '2016-05-24T14:13:25.267566'}}
[TRACE   ] func get_cli_event_returns()
[DEBUG   ] LazyLoaded local_cache.get_load
[DEBUG   ] get_iter_returns for jid 20160524161325275691 sent to set(['salt01-master']) will timeout at 16:13:30.282984
[DEBUG   ] jid 20160524161325275691 return from salt01-master
[DEBUG   ] LazyLoaded nested.output
[TRACE   ] data = {'salt01-master': True}
salt01-master:
    True

real    0m5.236s
user    0m0.236s
sys 0m0.034s
```

**"Trace" Output of the Environment that just runs fine.**

```
root@salt01-master:~# time salt -l trace 'salt01-master' test.ping
[DEBUG   ] Reading configuration from /etc/salt/master
[DEBUG   ] Using cached minion ID from /etc/salt/minion_id: salt01-master
[DEBUG   ] Missing configuration file: /home/admin-user/.saltrc
[TRACE   ] None of the required configuration sections, 'logstash_udp_handler' and 'logstash_zmq_handler', were found the in the configuration. Not loading the Logstash logging handlers module.
[DEBUG   ] Configuration file path: /etc/salt/master
[DEBUG   ] Reading configuration from /etc/salt/master
[DEBUG   ] Using cached minion ID from /etc/salt/minion_id: salt01-master
[DEBUG   ] Missing configuration file: /home/admin-user/.saltrc
[DEBUG   ] MasterEvent PUB socket URI: ipc:///var/run/salt/master/master_event_pub.ipc
[DEBUG   ] MasterEvent PULL socket URI: ipc:///var/run/salt/master/master_event_pull.ipc
[DEBUG   ] Sending event - data = {'_stamp': '2016-05-24T14:13:53.621800'}
[TRACE   ] get_event() received = {'tag': 'salt/event/new_client', 'data': {'_stamp': '2016-05-24T14:13:53.621800'}}
[TRACE   ] func get_cli_event_returns()
[DEBUG   ] LazyLoaded local_cache.get_load
[DEBUG   ] get_iter_returns for jid 20160524161353631575 sent to set(['salt01-master']) will timeout at 16:13:58.637479
[DEBUG   ] jid 20160524161353631575 return from salt01-master
[DEBUG   ] LazyLoaded nested.output
[TRACE   ] data = {'salt01-master': True}
salt01-master:
    True
[DEBUG   ] jid 20160524161353631575 found all minions set(['salt01-master'])

real    0m0.283s
user    0m0.179s
sys 0m0.029s
```

The Environment that works fine has an additional [DEBUG] Line, right after the regular Output of the 'test.ping' command

Can anyone pint me into the right direction?

Thank you very much.

Comment: You can restart salt-master daemon with DEBUG log level and see what is actually happening. It will give you a hint where you get you 5s delay. Then depending on the results you can restart the answering salt-minion daemon with DEBUG and see what it is actually doing as well.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any accepted minion keys for minions that are offline or gone? This sounds like the Salt Master is waiting for some missing minions to respond.

Comment: All my Salt minions are Connected and answer instantaneous.